# How can I use SnakeAnim with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I would like to use Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim and I have a question. Is there an example how to create custom component in react-leaflet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the library and import `leaflet.polyline.snakeanim/L.Polyline.SnakeAnim.js`

then create a wrapper to call the necessary methods to trigger the animation. You can have a `startAnimation` prop to trigger the animation but you can adjust it to your needs:

```
... // imports here

const SnakeAnim = ({ startAnimation }) => {
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!startAnimation) return;
    const trd = [63.5, 11];
    const mad = [40.5, -3.5];
    const lnd = [51.5, -0.5];
    const ams = [52.3, 4.75];
    const vlc = [39.5, -0.5];

    const route = L.featureGroup([
      L.marker(trd, { icon }),
      L.polyline([trd, ams]),
      L.marker(ams, { icon }),
      L.polyline([ams, lnd]),
      L.marker(lnd, { icon }),
      L.polyline([lnd, mad]),
      L.marker(mad, { icon }),
      L.polyline([mad, vlc]),
      L.marker(vlc, { icon })
    ]);

    map.fitBounds(route.getBounds());

    map.addLayer(route);

    route.snakeIn();

    route.on("snakestart snake snakeend", ev => {
      console.log(ev.type);
    });
  }, [startAnimation]);

  return null;
};
```

Use it like this, import the wrapper inside react-leaflet's Map wrapper:

```
const [startAnimation, setStartAnimation] = useState(false);
  const startSnake = () => setStartAnimation(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Map center={position} zoom={zoom} style={{ height: "90vh" }}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <SnakeAnim startAnimation={startAnimation} />
      </Map>
      <button onClick={startSnake}>Snake it!</button>
    </>
  );
```

Create a btn add a listener and trigger the animation via a flag.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-use-snakeanim-with-react-leaflet-g4gd2?file=/src/Map.jsx)

Comment: oh Thanks u so much, maybe u please tell me how can i render the L.featureGroup from an array of coordinate.. It's so complex :<

Comment: Please create another question for that as it is a different issue.

Comment: i see, I just create another question and here is the link 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62215914/how-can-i-render-the-l-featuregroup-from-an-array-of-coordinate)
Could u help me with that :<

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question and provide all the necessary details required to reproduce the issue. Provide the array of coordinates and anything else needed. Be specific so people can help you.

Comment: i'm so sorry about that, this is my first time use stackoverflow, I already fixed that question.

Answer (score 0):

another solutions using featuregroup  - you can place all polylines under FeatureGroup like below

```
<FeatureGroup ref={groupRefPolyline}>
     {polyLines.filter((polyline) => polyline[0] && polyline[0][0])
        .map((polyline, index) => {
             return (
                    <Polyline
                      key={index}
                      positions={polyline}
                    />
             )
      })}
</FeatureGroup>
```

and then invoke snakeIn

```
const group = groupRefPolyline?.current
if (group) {
  group.snakeIn()
}
```